# Switching of execution between 2 threads in C++, if threads involve a loop between mutex lock & unlock

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, mutex

I've a vector of strings which is a shared resourse.

```
std::vector<std::string> vecstr;
```

Have 2 threads which run in parallel:

Thread1: To insert strings to shared resourse.

Thread2: To calculate the size of the  shared resourse.

```
std::mutex mt;

void f1()
{
   mt.lock();
    while(some_condition())
   {
        std::string str = getStringFromSomewhere();
          vecstr.push_back(str);

   }

    mt.unlock();
}

size_t f2()
{
    mt.lock();
    while(string_sending_hasEnded())
    {
        size_t size = vecstr.size();
    }
    mt.unlock();
}

int main()
{
std::thread t1(f1);
std::thread t2(f2);
t1.join();
t2.join();

}
```

My question is : if the t1 thread keeps the vecstr shared resource mutex locked for the entire while loop duration how will the t2 get hold of the shared resource vecstr to calculate it's size ?
Does the execution keep switching between the 2 threads or it depends on who gets hold of mutex 1st. So if T1 got hold of mutex then it will release it only after while loop ends ? Is this true ? Or the execution keeps switching between the 2 threads.

> If any one of the thread is going to hijack the execution by not
>   allowing other thread to be switched in between then  how do i handle
>   such a scenario with while/for loops in each thread but both threads
>   needs to be continuously executed ?  Where I want both the threads to
>   keep switching their execution. Shall I lock and unlock inside the
>   while loop, so that each iteration has mutex locked & unlocked ?

Comment: Bear in mind that the calculated size will be kind of irrelevant, i.e. you'll just have an indication of what the shared resource's size was at some point in the past. It isn't clear how you want to use that information.

Comment: Since this is the version with the answers I think we should mark the other version as a duplicate of this rather than the other way round. (**done**)

Comment: what is your `f2()` thread supposed to do?  As it is written, it looks like it will either immediately die without doing anything at all (if "string sending" has not "ended"), or else it will loop forever without doing anything useful (if "string sending" _has_ "ended").

Comment: What does it even mean to calculate the size of a vector while at the same time, some other thread is continually growing the vector?  How will you know whether the thread has calculated the right answer?

Comment: Re, "... I want both the threads to keep switching their execution." If you think you want two threads to take turns doing something, then  what you _really_ want is a single thread that does both things in the right order.

Comment: @Jameslarge: I have a certai logic, wherein I want to do something when the size grows to a multiple of some size "n".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So if T1 got hold of mutex then it will release it only after while loop ends ? Is this true ?

Yes, that's true.

Either of the threads will lock the `mt` mutex over the whole time these loops are executed.

---

As for [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129233/switching-of-execution-between-2-threads-in-c-if-threads-involve-a-loop-betwe#comment77228067_45129249)

> If that's the case how do i handle such a scenario ? Where I want both the threads to keep switching their execution. Shall I lock and unlock inside the while loop, so that each iteration has mutex locked & unlocked

Yes use more fine grained locking, just for the operations that change/access the vector:

```
std::mutex mt;

void f1() {
    while(some_condition()) {
        std::string str = getStringFromSomewhere();
        { std::unique_lock(mt);    // -+
          vecstr.push_back(str);   //  | locked
        }                          // -+
    }
}

size_t f2() {
    while(string_sending_hasEnded()) {
        size_t size = 0;
        { std::unique_lock(mt);   // -+
          size = vecstr.size();   //  | locked
        }                         // -+
    }
}
```

I also highly recommend to use a lock-guard (as the `std::unique_lock` in my example), instead of using `lock()` `unock()` yourself manually. So it's safe that the mutex will be unlocked, e.g. in case of exceptions thrown.

Comment: If that's the case how do i handle such a scenario ? Where I want both the threads to keep switching their execution. Shall I lock and unlock inside the while loop, so that each iteration has mutex locked & unlocked ?

Comment: @codeLover Use more fine grained locking, e.g. only lock when you're changing something in the vector. Use a `std::lock_guard` with the `push_back()` operation and accessing the `size()`.

Comment: Thank you. Will locking  in the fashion  as showed by you, make the execution  switch between the 2 threads ?.

Answer (score 3):

You got it. If you want to use mutexes successfully in real life, you will keep a mutex looked only for the smallest amount of time possible. For example just around the push_back() and size() calls.

But really, what you need to do first is figure out what your program is supposed to do, and then use mutexes to make sure to achieve that. At the moment I know that you want to run some threads, but that's not what you want to achieve.